android static object loses its member object
public class MyTest { 
    static MyTest instance = null; 
    Context appctx = null;
    public static MyTest Instance() {
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new MyTest();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    // call from Application onCreate  MyTest.Instance().onAppCreate(this);
    public void onAppCreate(Context context) {
        appctx = context;
    }
    // call from Activity onCreate MyTest.Instance().onActivityCreate(this);
    public void onActivityCreate(Activity act) {
        if (null == appctx) {
            Log.d("error", "null app");
        }
        //...
        //client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(appctx, gso);
    }
}

Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3851)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4027)
      at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2336)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:247)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8676)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
    Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Null context is not permitted.
      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.3.0:2)
      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.<init> (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.4.0:4)
      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.<init> (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.4.0:21)
      at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.<init> (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@21.0.0:2)
      at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getClient (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@21.0.0:2)

instance do not have any external calls except for the onAppCreate and onActivityCreate function calls.
Is appctx null because instance is reclaimed by gc?
Above is an abbreviated version of a class in my app. appctx would not be null in the onActivityCreate function, but why would appctx be null in some cases.

"Is appctx null because instance is reclaimed by gc?": no.

What is the scenario where it logs that appctx is null? This should never happen. Are you setting appctx to null anywhere?

@DavidWasser I reedited it and nowhere set appctx to null

Your singleton methods need synchronization. Otherwise you could create a second instance.

@user207421 Will the application and activity oncreate method be called in another thread?

Application.onCreate() and Activity.onCreate() are both called on the main (UI) thread. synchronization is theoretically correct, but in this case I don't think it is necessary.

Makes no sense. Your code looks fine. Can you reproduce this? If so, add some logging to the methods in MyTest to see what is happening

@DavidWasser I can't reproduce it. about 1/1000 users are experiencing this exception

I don't see anything wrong. Even if your app is pushed to the background and killed off by Android, when the users return to it, first Application.onCreate() will be called and then Activity.onCreate() will be called. So you'll need to see if you can gather more data when this crash occurs.
